# Substring console output using std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

Is it possible to substring console output of an `std::string` using `std::string_view`?

For example:

```
std::string toolong {"this is a string too long for me"};  
std::string_view(toolong);
// do something...
```

expected console output: `this is a string`

Comment: Like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr)?

Comment: Please explain specifically how"too long" is defined. Also, whether you only want to format output, or you actually need a `string_view` (there might be other, display-only ways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called substring-ing.

```cpp
std::string toolong {"this is a string too long for me"};  
std::string_view view(toolong);

std::cout << view.substr(0, 16);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`remove_prefix()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/remove_prefix) and [`remove_suffix()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/remove_suffix) methods as well.

Example:

```
view.remove_suffix(16); // view is now "this is a string"

view.remove_prefix(5); // view is now -> "is a string"
```

If you want to do it in-place without creating a variable of `string_view`, use `substr()`

```
std::string toolong {"this is a string too long for me"};  
std::cout << std::string_view (toolong).substr(0, 16);
```